# sccm 2007 agent fail to install on windows xp client machine even after manually tried to install agent

Tags: windows-xp, sccm, sccm-2007

We have about 1000 client machine with XP SP3 in our network.

As you know Microsoft stopped supporting XP. now we cant install SCCM 2007 agent on our xp machines remotely. because windows update agent are not up to date in these machines.

But my problem is that when i try to install agent manually after installing the agent, in most cases i cant fined sccm 2007 agent in control panel.

Is it a common issue?

Comment: When installing manually, you should be able to check the event logs and sccm's own logs to determine if the agent was successfully installed or not, and if not, then the error code and/or reason. Have you checked these logs?

Comment: No. Where can i fined these logs?